# Sort-Object: Can it use an object's method result for sorting?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.3

Using [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) I added a tiny method to an array of objects to calculate sort of a hash from a string:

```
$arr | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name 'SortedName' -Value {
    [string]$name = $this.Name
    [int]$start = [int][char]$name[0];
    [int]$index = [int]($name -replace '^.+?(\d+)\.[^.]+$','$1')

    [int]"$start$('{0:D4}' -f $index)"
}
```

Now I'd like to sort the array using `$arr | Sort-Object -PropertyName 'SortedName'`. But that doesn't seem to work as expected.

How can I apply [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) on an array's methods?

Comment: Can you give an example of what `$arr` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To invoke methods on each element you need to use a [calculated expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3#sort-object).

For example:

```
$arr = 0..10 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{ Name = 'Test' + (Get-Random -Maximum 20) }
}

$arr | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name SortedName -Value {
    [int] ($this.Name -replace '\D+')
}

$arr | Sort-Object { $_.SortedName() }
```

Comment: Awesome! … I haven't read about calculated expressions before. Thanks! 